# random line breaks only on Ipad

Tags: html, css, ipad, break, line-breaks

for some reason I am only getting these weird line breaks on ipad, no idea why

http://www.tigerstudiodesign.com/sandbox/contact-us/

it gives it a line break after P: and F: on ipad, but no other browsers seem to do it.
no idea, seems to only happen on ipad, safari/chrome/FF/ie seem to not have a problem with it.

Comment: Have you got a screenshot we can see?

Comment: http://localhostr.com/files/CFspPYI/Screen+shot+2011-09-09+at+11.26.15+AM.jpg

Comment: http://localhostr.com/files/5Mm2QgP/Screen+shot+2011-09-09+at+11.27.15+AM.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try disabling phone number detection,

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

The iPad highlights phone numbers so you can add them to contacts and it might be messing with the spacing.

Comment: is there any way to style these? I don't like how they are by default white.